# Is SSL/TLS still secure enough?

Tags: security, ssl, openssl

It is said here :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption

> "a number of practical attacks has been introduced into production
>   protocols and applications by incorrect implementation, or lack of,
>   authentication (**including SSL/TLS**)"

So is SSL/TLS still secure enough ?
What's the risk (new kind of attack) ?
If not what to do now to really secure web servers ?

Comment: You should probably do some more research (e.g. read the source for that part of the article) and then ask on [security.se].

Comment: I have already done some reasearch reading advanced papers like http://cr.yp.to/talks/2013.03.12/slides.pdf ... I cannot understand so my question :)

Comment: Meh, if you think that's an advanced paper you won't get very far in this topic ;-) Still, there are more casual descriptions of these attacks (though probably not a single resource that describes all these attacks) - not any simpler conceptually, but with more hand-waving and less mathematical notation.

Comment: Please note that TLS does not secure web servers, at best it secures the exchanges between the client and the server.